# Implementing pinch to zoom(as present in UIWebView) in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uitextview, pinchzoom

I would like to implement simple, **zoom-in-out** Functionality in my iOS app which has UITextViews present in a TableView.
I am expecting a behaviour something similar to the Apple pages app(Document zoom).

How to achieve such an effect?

Answer (score 1):

[UIGestureRecognizer](http://yandex.ru/yandsearch?text=UIGestureRecognizer&clid=1955453&lr=192) will solve your problem.

Comment: To which view should I add the GestureRecognizer and how should I handle the Text in the textviews so that they don't blur out when zoomed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use UIPinchGestureRecognizer & UIGestureRecognizerDelegate together